# Mount Windows drive in Eclipse from Linux

Tags: java

I am trying to mount a windows drive in Eclipse from Linux. Is that even possible?This is my approach

```
String cmd = "MOUNTVOL " + volumeToMount + " " + mountPoint;
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdStr);
```

If I am going wrong anywhere,please let me know if there is any other way of achieving this.

Comment: Is my question clear? I really need help here.

Comment: Is this a local drive with a windows partition, or a windows share over the network?

Comment: windows share over the network

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, u need root to do mount operation. Secondly, Java runs on a virtual machine and I am not sure as how much power do the Java APIs give you in terms of permissions. Thirdly, is your syntax for mounting correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct. But I'm not sure if it is possible to execute that from eclipse, that too from linux OS.And I have logged in as root.

Comment: Seriously, no switches, no file system types, no information on permissions (read/write etc).

Answer (score 0):

Only the root can run the mount command. So, even if you succeed in constructing the mount command, it won't work unless you run the resulting Java application as the root.

Eclipse is really entirely beside the point. It is a Java program you are writing, and you just happen to be using Eclipse to edit it.